# Xamarin.Forms: Display additional tab on specific Platform

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

Good morning

I have a TabbedPage in my application. Due to restictions I would like to display one more tab on Android than on iOS.

My current TabbedPage look like:

```
<TabbedPage>

...

<ContentPage x:Name="Page1"/>
<ContentPage x:Name="Page2"/>
<ContentPage x:Name="Page3"/>
<ContentPage x:Name="Page4"/>
</TabbedPage>
```

I have decided to render Page3 only for Android. I changed my code into:

```
<TabbedPage>

...

<ContentPage x:Name="Page1"/>
<ContentPage x:Name="Page2"/>

<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Page">
    <On Platform="Android">
        <On.Value>
            <ContentPage x:Name="Page3"/>
        </On.Value>
    </On>
</OnPlatform>

<ContentPage x:Name="Page4"/>
</TabbedPage>
```

This leads to runtime exception when entering into this TabbedPage:

> An error occurred: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: item'.
> Callstack: '  at
> Xamarin.Forms.ObservableWrapper`2[TTrack,TRestrict].Add (TRestrict
> item) [0x00008] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\ObservableWrapper.cs:27

I tried to remove x:Name but did not work. Any ideas?

PS. As a workaround I am always able to:

```
Constructor()
{
   if(Runtime.IsIOS)
   {
       this.Children.Remove(this.Page3)  
   }
}
```

However would be better to not render it at all and have it at XAML level.

Comment: instead of removing it for iOS, why not just add it for Android in code?

Comment: As I wrote I cannot do it due to buisness restrictions

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this in XAML.  But it should be easy to do in code - `if (Runtime.IsAndroid) this.Children.Add(new Page3());`

Comment: That is the option which I wrote in the question :)

Comment: Not the same. You showed removing a page on iOS. Jason shows adding the page only on Android. Don’t put it in your xaml at all. To reference in code, have a declaration `private Page page3;` then `if (Runtime.IsAndroid) { page3 = new Page3(); Children.Add(page3); }`.

Comment: My apologise. That is true. This solution also is in code behind

Answer (score 1):

Unless someone comes up with a way to do this in XAML, this is the best you can do (building on Jason's comment):

xaml:

```xml
<ContentPage x:Name="Page1"/>
<ContentPage x:Name="Page2"/>
<!-- no Page3 in XAML -->
<ContentPage x:Name="Page4"/>
```

c#:

```cs
private ContentPage page3;

Constructor()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (Runtime.IsAndroid)
    {
        page3 = new ContentPage();
        // After pages 1 and 2.
        Children.Insert(2, page3);
    }
}

    // Elsewhere in code-behind.
        if (page3 != null)
        {
            ...refer to page3...
        }
```

This has the advantage of not constructing the page at all on iOS.
It also makes it easy to test whether page3 is there (`page3 != null`).

In practice, the other pages will typically be their own classes. Given `partial class Page3 : ContentPage` elsewhere:

```cs
private Page3 page3;

    ...
    page3 = new Page3();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/),xaml is an alternative to programming code for **instantiating and initializing objects**, and organizing those objects in parent-child hierarchies.If you add one additional tab on android it will cause a **NullReferenceException** on ios.So you may want to do it in codebehind with **Device.RuntimePlatform**.
Here is  my test you can refer to:

```
switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
        {
            case Device.Android:
                Children.Add(page1);
                Children.Add(page2);
                break;
            case Device.iOS:
                Children.Add(page1);
               
                break;
            case Device.UWP:
                Children.Add(page1);
                break;
        }
```